# Getting the error "type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast"

Tags: http, dictionary, post, dart

I get an error when I run the following code:

```
http.post(url,
body: {"access_token": "bfa67f6f8389f421d8ac0106f040d19b40d8a69112402a76b87d66aea86a",
  "title": "HelloWorld!",
  "content": [{
    "tag": "p",
      "children": 
        ["Hello world!"]
      }
    ],
  "return_content": true
},
```

I know that dart is complaining because I have an [array which contains a map within my map](https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Yo-Dawg-Heard-You.jpg).
How can I deal with this?

**EDIT:** I would normally encode it as JSON but the [API](https://telegra.ph/api) only accepts strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` argument must have type `String`, and it doesn't.
Your value looks like a JSON-like structure, so you probably want to encode that object structure as a String using the `json` encoder:

```
import "dart:convert";
...
var body = jsonEncode({"access_token": "..... " ... });
http.post(url, body: body);
```

Comment: That is initially what I thought but I'm unable to do that as the API does not accept JSON but only a string..

Comment: The result of `jsonEncode` *is* a string. The JSON format is a text format for representing structured data. The argument in your code here is that structured data, not the JSON encoding of it, so you need to convert it to a string, which is what `jsonEncode` does.

Comment: Many years later and I am wiser.. my mistake here was not deeply understanding types. I also think there was an issue with parsing the nested map, but it's all probably resolved by now.